# Can't read a text with '\n' in PhaserJS

Tags: string, game-development, line-breaks, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I' ve got a text displayed in PhaserJS 3 game, then the method onEvent runs on loop adding new text to the current text, it works until it finds '\n', but it gives no error at all.

```
function create() {
    this.savedText = this.add.text(0, 100, "Starting text display")
    this.newText = "This text should be displayed \n in two lines"
    this.index  = 0
    this.timedEvent = this.time.addEvent({ delay: 100, callback: this.onEvent, callbackScope: this, loop: true })
}

onEvent() {
    let textDisplayed = ""    
    if(this.index < parseInt(this.newText.length)) {
        textDisplayed += this.newText.charAt(this.index)
        this.savedText.text += textDisplayed            
        this.index++
    }
}
```

How can I fix this? Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question, or is something missing? If it solved your issue, please consider accepting it with the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code you have posten, in your question, is 100% the same as in your application, you just missed the keyword `function` before `onEvent()`. Because your code seems to basically work:

**Here a working Demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    },
}; 

function create() {
  // I added some dots and newlines, at the end just for optical reasons
  this.savedText = this.add.text(20, 50, "Starting text display ...\n\n") 
  this.newText = "This text should be displayed \n in two lines"
  this.index = 0
  this.timedEvent = this.time.addEvent({ delay: 100, callback: onEvent, callbackScope: this, loop: true })
}

// here you missed the keyword `function`
function onEvent() {
  let textDisplayed = ""    
  if(this.index < parseInt(this.newText.length)) {
      textDisplayed += this.newText.charAt(this.index)
      this.savedText.text += textDisplayed            
      this.index++
  }
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

> **Tipp:** for future debugging and posting questions, check the Browser console and the Error message found there since this helps find the problem faster.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. In fact, in Phaser 3 you can't put the keyword function in methods such as onEvent, update, create, etc. It'll give an error and the code won't run

Comment: Yes you can, the demo it works. It depends how you are creating your **scene**. In my demo I'm creating the scene with an object ([like in this demo](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/scenes/scene%20from%20object.js&v=3.70.0 )). I assumed you too due to the `function` keyword before the `create`  function. If you create a Scene class ([like in this demo](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/scenes/scene%20from%20es6%20class.js&v=3.70.0)) you can't use the `function` inside the class, in that case the keyword `function` in front of the `create` function could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, it works, I guess the problem is that I was extending GameScene, so I could not use function keyword.